# Is there any need to use PrimeNG pDefer with Lazy Loading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

In our Angular 6 project we use PrimeNG lazy loading feature for p-tables. On the other hand, there is a Deferring mechanism in PrimeNG explained below:

*The defer directive is very helpful to lazily load huge datasets when you use data iteration components such as p-dataTable, p-dataList, p-dataGrid, and so on. The onLoad callback is used to query data from the data source on demand when the component becomes visible through page scrolling. The query is not initiated on page load so that the page is loaded quickly. A concrete example is implemented here:*

```
<div pDefer (onLoad)="loadData()">
    <ng-template>
        <p-dataTable [value]="employees">
            <p-column field="firstName" header="First Name"></p-column>
            <p-column field="lastName" header="Last Name"></p-column>
            <p-column field="profession" header="Profession"></p-column>
            <p-column field="department" header="Department"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

However, I am wondering what is we use lazy loading in this p-table as shown below. Because as far as I see on my try both of them, there is not an impach between them. Maybe I am wrong, is there any need to use Deferring mechanism (pDefer) with lazy loading?

```
<ng-template>
    <p-dataTable [value]="employees" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazyData($event)">
        <p-column field="firstName" header="First Name"></p-column>
        <p-column field="lastName" header="Last Name"></p-column>
        <p-column field="profession" header="Profession"></p-column>
        <p-column field="department" header="Department"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how is your p-dataTable lazy-loading works if you're not using it with a pager? How is loadLazyData function gets called?